# Possible to make SASS @extend styles !important?

Tags: sass

Is there a way to give SASS styles applied using the @extend feature the status of being !important? I tried this:

```sass
.somestyles {
    width: 1000px;
}
.importantstyle {
    @extend .somestyles !important;
}
```

Didn't work, but how might this be done? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: Idk, but I feel like this should turn into a feature.

Comment: That would be a very good idea

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible.  You could increase the specificity of the selector that's doing the extending.

```
body .importantstyle {
    @extend .somestyles;
}
```

Comment: Avoid comments like "thanks". Hum sorry but this time really just want to say thanks, it saves me a lot of time for sure.